# Ajax submit using a button

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I am using the code from this page: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_database.asp to build my ajax solution.

I am getting there, but this code use `onchange`, I would like to use a button to submit, instead.

One of my tries:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showCustomer(str)
{
var xmlhttp;    
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getcustomer.asp?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action=""> 
<select name="customers">
<option value="">Select a customer:</option>
<option value="ALFKI">Alfreds Futterkiste</option>
<option value="NORTS ">North/South</option>
<option value="WOLZA">Wolski Zajazd</option>
</select>
<input name="Submit1" type="submit" onclick="showCustomer(this.value)" />
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint">Customer info will be listed here...</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Provide a JSFiddle with your problem

Comment: You'll need to provide what you've done.  Your problem could either be in how you're creating your button, how you're attaching the event listener to it, or how you're performing the result of the event.

Comment: Just added what i've tried. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onchange is an event on a select element.

Just tie that event into a button element.

```
<button onclick="showCustomer()">Submit</button>
```

and then get the desired customer in the showCustomer() method

```
function showCustomer()
{
    var str = document.getElementById("customers").value;
    .
    .
    .
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getcustomer.asp?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: the submit is submiting but the value is empty, how can I get the value from the select like `this.value` in the selectbox? thanks

Answer (score 1):

they have the event attached to the select so you can just move it to the form instead

```
<form action="" onsubmit="showCustomer(document.getElementById('customers')).value);return false"> 
  <select id="customers" name="customers">
  <option value="">Select a customer:</option> 
  <option value="ALFKI">Alfreds Futterkiste</option>
  <option value="NORTS ">North/South</option>
  <option value="WOLZA">Wolski Zajazd</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

**Edit:**

Oh, and add a submit button

Comment: The url gets the value, and the form did not submit, or submited but isn't allright

Comment: Yes, I for got the `return false` to stop the form actually submitting. glad you got it sorted

Comment: Your tip with `return false` really help me too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showCustomer()
{
var xmlhttp;    
var str = document.getElementById("customers").value;
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getcustomer.asp?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>


<select name="customers">
<option value="">Select a customer:</option>
<option value="ALFKI">Alfreds Futterkiste</option>
<option value="NORTS ">North/South</option>
<option value="WOLZA">Wolski Zajazd</option>
</select>
<input name="Submit1" type="button" onclick="showCustomer()" />

<br>
<div id="txtHint">Customer info will be listed here...</div>

</body>
</html>
```

But you should try [Jquery](http://www.w3schools.com/Jquery/default.asp) to avoid verbose syntax `document.getElementById`